# Not enough Folds on CrossValidation from Scikit Learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I try to create a prediction model with Scikit Learn in Python. I have a dataframe with about 850k rows and 17 columns. The last column is my label and the others my features.

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import metrics

predictors = [a list of my predictors columns]

alg = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1, n_estimators=150, min_samples_split=8, min_samples_leaf=4)

scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(alg, train[predictors],train["Sales"], cv=5)

print(scores.mean())
```

However, when I run the code, I have the following warning:

```
/Users/.../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py:417: Warning: The least populated class in y has only 1 members, which is too few. The minimum number of labels for any class cannot be less than n_folds=5.
  % (min_labels, self.n_folds)), Warning)
```

I am not sure if I understood the warning message. I thought I would have it only on small samples.

Comment: The problem is the sparsity of classes in your target. What is frequency of classes in `y`?

Comment: @David Not sure if I understood well, but the `train["Sales"]` is an integer column from 0 to 10.000 with many different occurs. So, if you mean that the target has repeated values.

Comment: So it sounds like you're predicting a continuous variable opposed to a categorical one, correct? If so you should use regression and not classification, i.e.: `RandomForestRegressor`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by David in the comments, it sounds like your output is continuous instead of categorical. If this is the case, you almost certainly don't want to be performing classification, as opposed to regression.

The warning is stemming from the fact that (at least) one of the values in your targets, which are treated as categorical, is underrepresented. If you actually do want to perform classification, a good thing to do first would be to count the number of occurrences of each class in your entire training set.

When you do `k` fold cross-validation, and `min_labels` < `k`, one of the runs of the cross-validation is guaranteed not to see *any* examples of the class with `min_labels`, either at train or test time (more frequently happens at test time because the test sets are smaller). In the case that you only have 1 instance of a specific class, then further, you will be guaranteed to get a *training* run that doesn't see any examples of that class (it lies in one of the folds, which will be used as the test set once)